# gradient box dynamically append jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If click on button some boxes are append. next you will click on that boxes gradient box will append but gradient boxes are not appending.its append only first box if click on another box gradient box doesn't append

[image: screenshot]

[**My Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/swaroop206/fw748rua/46/)

```
     <script src="https://cdn.office24by7.com/add-templates/gradX.js"></script>

<button class="clbtn" name="button" value="button">button</button>

         <div class="appenddiv">
                </div>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;  

        $(".clbtn").click(function(el){

         $.fn.myFunction = function(){ 


    gradX("#clrpik", {
    targets: [".target"]
    });


            }

        $(".appenddiv").append('<div class="target"><div class="target_text">Click Here for gradient</div></div>');

     $(".target").click(function(){

    $(".appenddiv").append('<div id="clrpik"></div>').myFunction();

     }); 

        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: see updated answer add this

Comment: its not working

Comment: click on button 2 times after that two box will come.next you click on first box gradent box append .next you click on second box gradent box doesn't append.i want to append second gradent box

Answer (score 0):

Gradient box appending on other div click but it's stick to first div

use this to set:

```
$(this).append('<div id="clrpik"></div>').myFunction();

});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var f = 0; 


    $(".clbtn").click(function(el){
 
  $.fn.myFunction = function(){ 


gradX("#clrpik", {
targets: [".target"]
});
//f++; 
 
  
  }



    $(".appenddiv").append('<div class="target"><div class="target_text">Click Here for gradient</div></div>');

 $(".target").one('click', function(){
 
$(this).append('<div id="clrpik"></div>').myFunction();

});    
 
    });
 
});
```

```css
.targets {
                margin:0 auto;
                text-align: center;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                background: #f8f8f8;
                margin: 0 auto;
                border-radius: 4px;
                width:auto;
                padding:10px;
            }

            .target_text {
                margin: 0px auto;
                margin-top: 40%;
                background: #f8f8f8;
                width: 70px;
                border: 1px solid #ddd;
                padding: 2px;
                border-radius: 2px;
                color: #111;
            }

            .target {
                border: 1px solid;
                margin: 0px 10%;
                width: 150px;
                height: 150px;
                display:inline-block;
            }
            #target {
                border-radius: 150px;
            }

            .result {
                text-align: center;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-weight: bold;
                padding:12px;
                padding-left: 15px;
                margin: 10px 0px;
                border: 1px solid #ddd;
                background: #f8f8f8;
            }


            .clrpik {
                height: 200px; 
                margin: 100px 34%;            
            }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.office24by7.com/add-templates/colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.office24by7.com/add-templates/gradX.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://codologic.com/page/sites/all/files/gradx/dom-drag.js"></script>
<script src="https://codologic.com/page/sites/all/files/gradx/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdn.office24by7.com/add-templates/gradX.js"></script>
<button class="clbtn" name="button" value="button">button</button>
        
  <div class="appenddiv">
  </div>
```